# POST base64 png in XMLHTTP Request

Tags: javascript, php, post, base64

For some reason this information is impossible to find a straight forward answer for, I have been trying to solve this for over a week. So please give a useful answer to it only!

I am saving `canvas.toDataUrl` image into the server with the following steps:

JAVASCRIPT

```
function captureCanvas(){
    html2canvas(displayScreen).then(canvas =>{
        postPicture(canvas.toDataURL());
    })
}

function postPicture(data){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function (){
        if (this.status == 200){
         let result = document.getElementById('result-pic');   
         console.log('this is the response:'+this.response);
         result.src = this.response;
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'storeImage.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send('image='+data);
}
```

Then trying to store it with server side / display the result back into html file:
**PHP**

```
$baseFromJavascript = $_POST['image'];
$data = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/w+;base64,#i', '', $baseFromJavascript));
$filepath = "./upload/image.png";
file_put_contents($filepath,$data);

echo $baseFromJavascript;
```

Neither it's being opened as an image locally or being displayed into **html**, even though the **html img** has the **base64 data**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do some changes in Javscript as well as in PHP

Encode your data in JS so that request sent proper

```
function captureCanvas(){
    html2canvas(displayScreen).then(canvas =>{
        postPicture(canvas.toDataURL());
    })
}

function postPicture(data){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function (){
        if (this.status == 200){
         let result = document.getElementById('result-pic');   
         console.log('this is the response:'+this.response);
         result.src = this.response;
        }
    }
    xhr.open('POST', 'storeImage.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send('image='+encodeURIComponent(data));
}
```

Change your php script as below:

```
$baseFromJavascript = $_POST['image'];
$data = $baseFromJavascript;
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$filepath = "./upload/image.png";
file_put_contents($filepath,$data);

echo $baseFromJavascript;
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks for your help!